# Python: split strings and form dictionaries in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of string as follows:

```
e = ['Website: Alabama Office of the Attorney General',
 'Toll Free: 1-800-392-5658',
 'Website: State Banking Department',
 'Toll Free: 1-866-465-2279',
 'Website: Department of Insurance',
 'Phone Number: 334-241-4141',
 'Website: Securities Commission',
 'Phone Number: 334-242-2984',
 'Website: Public Service Commission',
 'Toll Free: 1-800-392-8050']
```

I want to form dictionaries by splitting the strings at ":" and form dictionaries of each two elements in the list like:

```
e = [{'Website': 'Alabama Office of the Attorney General',
 'Toll Free': '1-800-392-5658'},
 {'Website': 'State Banking Department',
 'Toll Free': '1-866-465-2279'},
 {'Website': 'Department of Insurance',
 'Phone Number': '334-241-4141'},
 {'Website': 'Securities Commission',
 'Phone Number': 334-242-2984'},
 {'Website': 'Public Service Commission',
 'Toll Free': '1-800-392-8050'}]
```

Thank you for your help as always.

Comment: Why do you want it to be in a list?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far to solve your problem. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: [so] is not a code writing service, please review [ask] and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Can you specify more how the format of the list works?

Comment: Sorry, @TemporalWolf and everyone, I'll be more careful next time. I just couldn't figure out a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a dictionary **per two lines**. You can use:

```
ei = iter(e)
[{k:v for k,v in (x.split(':',1) for x in xs)} for xs in zip(ei,ei)]
```

generating:

```
>>> [{k:v for k,v in (x.split(':',1) for x in xs)} for xs in zip(ei,ei)]
[{'Website': ' Alabama Office of the Attorney General', 'Toll Free': ' 1-800-392-5658'}, {'Website': ' State Banking Department', 'Toll Free': ' 1-866-465-2279'}, {'Website': ' Department of Insurance', 'Phone Number': ' 334-241-4141'}, {'Website': ' Securities Commission', 'Phone Number': ' 334-242-2984'}, {'Website': ' Public Service Commission', 'Toll Free': ' 1-800-392-8050'}]
```

Or better formatted:

```
>>> [{k:v for k,v in (x.split(':',1) for x in xs)} for xs in zip(ei,ei)]
[{'Website': ' Alabama Office of the Attorney General', 'Toll Free': ' 1-800-392-5658'},
 {'Website': ' State Banking Department', 'Toll Free': ' 1-866-465-2279'},
 {'Website': ' Department of Insurance', 'Phone Number': ' 334-241-4141'},
 {'Website': ' Securities Commission', 'Phone Number': ' 334-242-2984'},
 {'Website': ' Public Service Commission', 'Toll Free': ' 1-800-392-8050'}]
```

If you want to **remove the spaces in the value**, we can use `strip()`:

```
ei = iter(e)
[{k:v.strip() for k,v in (x.split(':',1) for x in xs)} for xs in zip(ei,ei)]
```

If there are ***`n`* lines per dictionary**, we can use:

```
n = 2
ei = iter(e)
[{k:v for k,v in (x.split(':',1) for x in xs)} for xs in zip(*((ei,)*n))]
```

Comment: How do we know that there won't be a Website, Phone Number, and then a Toll Free number?

Comment: @CoryMadden: we can easily generalize that. Working on it.

Comment: @CoryMadden: modified :)

Comment: Oh yea, no doubt that would work. What I meant was if the list were like this `['Website', 'Toll Free', 'Phone Number', 'Website', 'Toll Free', 'Website']`. But I'm probably reading too much into it. I don't think you'd be able to do it in a comprehension.

Comment: @CoryMadden: in that case, one can use an `iterable.groupby`. The problem is that currently that does not seem the case, and the OP does not answer the comments.

Comment: Thank you, Guys! I am going make pairs every two elements so your solution would work the best @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal: please add the specifications to the question. Such that the question is completely defined (and is useful for future readers).

Answer (score -1):

```
# Assumption :  Total 2*n entries are present
ans = []
for i in xrange(0, len(e), 2):
    website = e[i].strip().split(':')
    toll = e[i+1].strip().split(':')
    ans.append({website[0]:website[1], toll[0]:toll[1]})
```